# Terraform: modules + output from for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a Terraform script using modules. I want to create multiple resources so I'm using the for_each method.

Below is my variable configuration:

```
variable bridge_domains {
  description = "Bridge Domain"
  type     = map
  default  = {
    bd1 = {
      name  = "BD1",
    },
    bd2 = {
      name    = "BD2"
    }
  }
}
```

In the root `main.tf` file, I'm looping over that variable using `for_each`:

```
module "schema_template_bd" {
  source = "./modules/schema_template_bd"
  for_each     =    var.bridge_domains
  
  schema       =    module.tenant.mso_schema.id 
  template     =    var.template

  bd           =    each.value.name
}
```

Then in the `modules/schema_template_bd` file I have the following:

```
resource "mso_schema_template_bd" "bd" {
  schema_id              =      var.schema
  template_name          =      var.template
  name                   =      var.bd
}
```

The module has an output where I have defined the following:

```
output "mso_bd" {
  value = mso_schema_template_bd.bd[*]
}
```

The idea is to output the names from all the objects that were created. So I have defined an `output.tf` file (at root level) containing the following code:

```
output "bd_name" {
  value = module.schema_template_bd.mso_bd.*.name
}
```

I always get:

> This object does not have an attribute named "name".

Normally the `bd` object has a name so the error has to do with a wrong syntax in my view.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The `[*]` and `.*` operators are intended for use with lists only. Because this resource uses `for_each` rather than `count`, its value in other expressions is a *map*, not a list.

To make your configuration work you'll need to decide whether it's better to return a map of names where the keys are the `var.bridge_domains` keys, or to return just a set of ids where the caller then couldn't determine which name belongs to which of the elements of `var.bridge_domains`:

```
output "bd_name" {
  value = {
    for k, bd in mso_schema_template_bd.bd : k => bd.name
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
output "bd_name" {
  value = [
    for bd in mso_schema_template_bd.bd : bd.name
  ]
}
```

If only unique results are desirable in the second example, the function `toset` can be used:

```
output "bd_name" {
  value = toset([
    for bd in mso_schema_template_bd.bd : bd.name
  ])
}
```

This uses [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions), which are the more general counterpart of [splat expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) that work with collections of any type and which can produce both sequences and mappings as their result, whereas splat expressions work only with lists.

Comment: Both suggestions would go in the output file of the child modules, right?

Comment: I suppose I inadvertently combined both of your examples together while I was reading back to get the examples to modify. You may need to do something similar to this at both layers, or you could have the inner module just directly return `mso_schema_template_bd.bd` (with no `[*]` or any other operator) to expose the entire map of resource objects to the outer module.

Comment: The `tomap` function call in the first example is superfluous. A map comprehension already outputs a map. The `toset` function call in the second example is also not strictly necessary and only needed if one needs to exclude duplicates from the list.

Comment: The `{ for ... }` syntax actually technically constructs an _object-typed_ value, not a _map-typed_ value, and so `tomap` coerces it into a map. In this particular case the distinction probably doesn't matter, but when it comes to output values (which represent the API boundary between one module and another) I think it's worth being clear about what type you're intending to return.

Answer (score 59):

Leaving this here in case someone is interested

```
output "bd_name" {
  value = values(mso_schema_template_bd.bd).*.name
}
```

Comment: Same but using another syntax: `values(mso_schema_template_bd.bd)[*].name`